# Is there anyone on planet earth who know SocialAuth - SocialAuth throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException with no message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jsf-1.2, socialauth

I am using `SocialAuth` libraries to authenticate against Facebook in my `jsf` application. I am getting `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` exception with no message from `org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager`

The probable statement causing this is:

```
String providerUrl = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(Common.FACEBOOK_AS_ID, Common.SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL);
```

Any clue guys. Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue today trying to authenticate via Facebook with socialauth-4.0.

The solution is really simple, just make sure that the three jars (openid4java.jar, json-20080701.jar, commons-logging-1.1.jar) that are inside the folder **dependencies** (inside the zip archive of socialauth) are available at runtime.

In my case I had to put them in the lib folder of my tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is throw if the method called threw an exception.
Just unwrap the cause within the InvocationTargetException and you'll get to the original one.

```
try{
  String providerUrl = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(Common.FACEBOOK_AS_ID, Common.SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL);
}catch (InvocationTargetException ex) { 
   System.out.println("oops! "+ ex.getCause()) ;
}
```

This will tell you the actual problem, so you can resolve that issue.